# Check for only alphanumric

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I want to test all cells in column for only alphanumric values (i.e `HJ334`, `AA334`, `3345GG`) if not show an error message box.

My code is below. Would this work? Is there better way?

```
Sub test()
    Dim a$, b$, c$, i As Integer

    a$ = Range("A1").Value

    For i = 1 To Len(a$)
        b$ = Mid(a$, i, 1)
        If b$ Like "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]" Then
            c$ = c$ & b$
        End If
    Next i

    Range("A2").Value = c$
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you asking "would this work"? Have you not tested your code?

Comment: The `Like` operator looks wrong. Read the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, why should it be wrong?

Comment: Would you like replacing special characters? Can you edit your question and post two such initial strings, followed by the desired return?

Comment: *"Would this work?"* Yes, it would. • *"Is there better way?"* Yes, there is defenitely a better way than checking each character on its own.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ According to the documentation it should be `[A-Za-z0-9]` unless you can explain the purpose of the commas

Comment: @MonkeyZeus my bad, you are right this would except commas in the string too.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ No worries

Comment: Using RegExp will be the fastest method, I think. And create a function for the correct pattern.

Comment: i apologize all  this was wrong code and question  thanks for comments

Answer (score 3):

Try the next function, using `RegExp`. It needs a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5':

```
Function elimSpecialChars(strInput As String) As String
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            elimSpecialChars = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            elimSpecialChars = strInput
            Debug.Print "Nothing to be replaced"
        End If
End Function
```

It can be tested in this way:

```
Sub testelimSpecialChars()
   Debug.Print elimSpecialChars("ABC345__yT,,'56%@!`")
End Sub
```

You can use the next `Sub` to automatically add the required reference (or use late binding):

```
Sub addRegExpReference()
   'Add a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5':
   On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:="{3F4DACA7-160D-11D2-A8E9-00104B365C9F}", _
        Major:=5, Minor:=5
    If Err.Number = 32813 Then
        MsgBox "The reference already exists..."
    Else
        MsgBox "The reference added sucressfully..."
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The above function is able to eliminate the illegal characters. Since you do not need it as it is, I will adapt it in order to only check:

```
Function stringOK(strInput As String) As Boolean
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^A-Z0-9]"
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If Not regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            stringOK = True
        End If
End Function
```

It can be used in a dynamic range in the next way:

```
Sub testIllegalChars()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not stringOK(CStr(arr(i, 1))) Then
        MsgBox "Illegal characters on range ""A" & i + 1 & """ (" & arr(i, 1) & ")."
        sh.Range("A" & i + 1).Select: Exit Sub
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

But the simplest way would be the solution using `Like` proposed by @JvdV. I will transform it in a function, but all the credit must go to him:

```
Function stringOK(str As String) As Boolean
    If Not UCase(str) Like "*[!A-Z0-9]*" Then stringOK = True
End Function
```

Comment: sorry im lost today what i am trying to ask is is there a code i can use that test all cells in column to make sure only alphanumric values are present ? i.e J232, 453H

Comment: @Kidus Yohans: Of course. I will edit the answer and put a piece of code to show you how to proceed.

Comment: @Kidus Yohans:  Updated the answer with a piece of code showing how to use the function on a range. But do you want only checking if special character exist, or to eliminate them? My code eliminate every character except alphanumeric ones... It can be easily adapted if only checking is necessary, but in such a case, what to return in case of such character existence? To stop and warn with a message?

Comment: @Kidus Yohans: Now, I have to leave my office. If something unclear or different, I can solve after some hours when being at home... Even a faster way of checking/changing.

Comment: i need a msg box if a non alphanumric value is found , columns should only have (i.e J377, 787H)  thanks

Comment: Upvoted but two things to keep in mind. You can speed things up by a mile if you first load the values into an array. 2nd, I don't even think we need to use a regular expression (which is quite slow). `Like` can actually also check these values as a whole.

Comment: @JvdV  is there a way to make dynamic? because there could multiple combos of letters and numbers (ie J3455, K3546 or 7654H)

Comment: @JvdV this is what i have so far        If Not c.text Like "J3425" Then MsgBox "Error"

Comment: @JvdV: Thanks! But i did not understand (until now) which is the OP's need. I understood that he needs to eliminate all the other characters than alphanumeric. The function I posted does not only check if such characters exist. This can be easily done using like. It determines which are these characters and eliminate them (using `Replace`). And, yes, I all the time use arrays. In all my answers which can involve such a solution. I preferred to show him a version easy to be understood, like a beginner. I asked him about his real need and told him about a faster way. Of course, the array version

Comment: If you do not need to replace the illegal characters, I will edit my answer and post another function and a faster way to check a specific range.

Answer (score 2):

**Like**

You can check your whole string in a single go if you are creative with the possibilities within the `Like` operator. We can actually negate a character class using the exclamation mark:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "GG123"
Debug.Print Not UCase(str) Like "*[!A-Z0-9]*"

End Sub
```

Using the wildcards at the sides of the character class we look if a string holds any character other than upper-case letters or digits. If so, it will return `FALSE` (because I used `Not()`).

---

**Regex**

A very common way to check pattern, and way more versatile than `Like`, but probably slower:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "3345GG"
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^[\da-z]+$"
    .Ignorecase = True
    Debug.Print .Test(str)
End With

End Sub
```

The pattern used means:

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `[\da-z]+` - Any digit or letter from a-z at least once.
- `$` - End string ancor.

The `IgnoreCase` property is set to `TRUE` meaning we don't have to include upper-case letters in our class.

---

**FilterXML()**

Just for the sake of alternatives, and I didn't do any testing on performance, you could utilize `FILTERXML()`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "3345GG"
Debug.Print Not IsError(Application.FilterXML("<t><s>" & UCase(str) & "</s></t>", "//s[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789','')='']"))

End Sub
```

Who know, if one has Excel 2013 or higher, it might actually be faster than regex.

Comment: sorry im lost today what i am trying to ask is is there a code i can use that test all cells in column to make sure only alphanumric values are present ? i.e J232, 453H

Comment: I think the other answer will show you how to loop through cells (though I'd use an array for speed). Many other questions around on SO showing you how to loop a range. Should I keep the answer as a reference for a better way to check your values?

Comment: Can't abstain from liking a post titled **Like** +:)