# Clear text of specific characters in a celll with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, data-cleaning

I'm looking for some help please with some VBA.

I have the next table

| header1 |
| --- |
| 000Model Test0Model Val00User0 |
| Perman000User0Model Name000000 |
| 000Perman00000000000000000000Name |

So I need to replace all Ceros with only one "," like this

| header1 |
| --- |
| ,Model Test,Model Val,User, |
| Perman,User,Model Name, |
| ,Perman,Name |

Is there a combination of formulas to do this? or with code in VBA?

Comment: While `Instr()` finds "00" in the text, replace "00" with "0". Finally replace "0" with ","

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function replace0(x As String) As String
    Dim matches As Object, mch As Object, arr, k As Long
    ReDim arr(Len(x))
     With CreateObject("VbScript.regexp")
        Pattern = "[0]{1,30}"
        .Global = True
        If .test(x) Then
            replace0 = .replace(x, ",")
        End If
     End With
End Function
```

It can be tested using:

```
Sub replaceAllzeroByComma()
   Dim x As String
   x = "000Perman00000000000000000000Name"
   'x = "000Model Test0Model Val00User0"
   'x = "Perman000User0Model Name000000"
   Debug.Print replace0(x)
End Sub
```

Uncheck the checked lines, one at a time and see the result in `Immediate Window` (`Ctrl + G`, being in VBE)

Comment: Is there early binding of `CreateObject("VbScript.regexp")` ?

Comment: @Waleed  Of course, it is. If I remember well, I have a piece of code able to automatically add the necessary reference (knowing a specific GUIDE). it  needs a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5'. Early binding makes the code a little faster and offers intellisense options. I am using late binding, from some time, only to avoid explaining to people (many of them not even knowing what a reference is) how to add such a necessary reference.

Comment: See Regex GUID example at [Check for only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127026/check-for-only-alphanumric/65127627#65127627). - *Fyi You might be interested in my late post to this question demonstrating some alternative steps by atomizing a string*

Comment: @Waleed you can see the code I was talking about in my above comment in the link posted by T.M. (couldn't use two tags...).

Comment: @T.M. It looks interesting, voted it up. No time now to digest it...:)

Comment: @Waleed No availability now for such a task. Since, events cannot be disabled in forms, basically, you should use some global boolean variables to switch between different ways of acting in case of events triggered by the code changes. It looks complex enough, but I suppose it can be done...

Answer (score 2):

If you have Microsoft 365, you can use:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1)="0",",","")&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"0"))&IF(RIGHT(A1)="0",",","")
```

- Split on the zero's
- Join the split text with a comma delimiter
- Have to specially test first character
- and also the last character as pointed out by @T.M.

[image]

Comment: Nice +:) ... and to specially test last character as well: `=IF(LEFT(A1)="0",",","")&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"0"))&IF(RIGHT(A1)="0",",","")`   @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @T.M. That was an oversight of mine. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to check a character array as follows:

- a) atomize input string to a `tmp` array of single characters via `String2Arr()`
- b) check for zero characters in `tmp` via `CheckChar`
- c) execute a negative filtering preserving first zeros in each 0-sequence via `Filter(tmp, delChar, False)`
- d) return joined string

```
Function Rep0(ByVal s As String, Optional delChar As String = "0")
'Purp.: replace first zero in each 0-sequence by ",", delete any remaining zeros
    Dim tmp: tmp = String2Arr(s)        ' a) atomize string to character array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)  ' b) check zero characters
        Dim old As String: CheckChar tmp, i, old, delChar
    Next
    tmp = Filter(tmp, delChar, False)   ' c) negative filtering preserving non-deletes
    Rep0 = Join(tmp, vbNullString)      ' d) return cleared string
End Function
```

**Help procedures**

```
Sub CheckChar(ByRef arr, ByRef i As Long, ByRef old As String, _
              ByVal delChar As String, Optional replChar As String = ",")
'Purp.: replace 1st delChar "0" in array (depending on old predecessor)
        If Left(arr(i), 1) = delChar Then   ' omit possible string end character
            If Not old Like "[" & delChar & replChar & "]" Then arr(i) = replChar
        End If
        old = arr(i)                        ' remember prior character
End Sub
```

```
Function String2Arr(ByVal s As String)
'Purp.: atomize input string to single characters array
    s = StrConv(s, vbUnicode)
    String2Arr = Split(s, vbNullChar, Len(s) \ 2)
End Function
```